# VS 2022: There is no template Blazor Server App

Tags: blazor, visual-studio-2022

VS 2022  Version 17.5.0 Preview 6.0

I want to create a Blazor Server app : in the VS 2022 but see only 3 templates:

```
Blazor Server App Empty
Blazor WebAssembly App Empty
NETMAUI Blazor App
```

But here is no Blazor Server App template.
I try to reproduce this:
https://thecodeblogger.com/2022/09/28/net-7-getting-started-with-blazor-server-app/

Why the VS by the link has these templates. What is the problem with my VS 2022?
Can I add template to VS 2022?
The VS suggests me NET 7 only. How can I use NET 6?

Comment: I would start by running the Installer app and add the dotnet6 sdk. Maybe net7 relies on that.

Comment: It is installed

Comment: Well, double-check that. Can you select net6 for other project types? And look for a 'Repair' option.   I can select all Blazor templates in the same Preview version.

Comment: Do you have the "Blazor Server App"  besides these 3?

Comment: Also, no any ASP.NET project templates

Comment: YES!!!! Write it as an Answer and I will mark it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blazor is part of ASP.NET and that requires the "ASP.NET and web development" workload to be installed.

You can get at the installer screen with the `Tools`|`Get Tools and Features` menu item.

Comment: Дякую! Слава Україні!